# Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity' erorr when adding multiple mailboxes to one user

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to add multiple mailboxes from a CSV file in MS Exchange Powershell module, but I am receiving the below error:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot 
convert value "@{identity=sharedmailbox@mail.com}" to type
"Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParameter".
Error: "Cannot convert the "@{identity=sharedmailbox@mail.com}" value of
type "Deserialized.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type
"Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParameter"."
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-MailboxPermission], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Add-MailboxPermission
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

Below you can see the script:

```
$names = Import-Csv -Path “X:\X\names.csv” -Delimiter ";"

foreach ($identity in $names) {
    Add-ExoMailboxPermission -Identity $identity -User First.Last@mail.com -AccessRights FullAccess -AutoMapping:$false
}
```

Comment: `-Identity $identity` -> `-Identity $identity.identity`

Comment: Also, please do not wrap code in arbitrary places. That will more often than not introduce additional bugs in the code, which may mislead people trying to help.